# Porting to WinRT apps: How to use NMAKE to call winRT apps in build process

Tags: windows-runtime, porting, nmake

I am trying to port an open source library to WinRT.

In original setup few projects would compile to form .exe which were then called by a makefile using NMAKE. These .exe used to prepare a data .dll from .txt(raw data files).

Now for porting i have converted all the exe projects into winRT apps. This is did by adding Package.appxmanifest files and assests folder. Also making changes in project settings of all the exe.

In the configuration manager, I have checked the option to deploy after building for all these apps. Now i need to call these exe. How to do this?

Please help.

Comment: Are these executables only used at build-time?

Comment: Yes. They will not run on WinRT machine.

Comment: Then why did you make them Windows Store apps?  If they only run during build, just leave them as normal desktop apps.

Comment: These exe prepare a dll icudt40.dll. This is a data dll. As you said i would now try to use the data dll built on win8 desktop using VS2012 and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Ok . I would try to use data dll built by these exe's in my WinRT app.
I have another query. Can i use the winrt ported Code dll in a win8 desktop exe. Actually i have a test framework which i havent ported yet. I tried to use the win8 exe with 1) winrt ported code dll & 2) win8 data dll.
Thanks